# value_from_datadict: hard to understand

Tags: django, django-forms

I dont understand the example [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.MultiWidget):

```
def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
    datelist = [
        widget.value_from_datadict(data, files, name + '_%s' % i)
        for i, widget in enumerate(self.widgets)]
    try:
        D = date(
            day=int(datelist[0]),
            month=int(datelist[1]),
            year=int(datelist[2]),
        )
    except ValueError:
        return ''
    else:
        return str(D)
```

Specifically, I dont understand when we should use `widget.value_from_datadict()` and how we can use it. If you look at the source code itself it's not documented at all (`django\forms\widgets.py`):

```
def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
    return [widget.value_from_datadict(data, files, name + '_%s' % i) for i, widget in enumerate(self.widgets)]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`value_from_datadict()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.value_from_datadict) is a method of the [`Widget`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget) abstract class which as per its [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.value_from_datadict()) string:

```
def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
    """
    Given a dictionary of data and this widget's name, returns the value
    of this widget. Returns None if it's not provided.
    """
    return data.get(name)
```

In your specific case - from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.MultiWidget.format_output) I assume

```
def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
    datelist = [
        widget.value_from_datadict(data, files, name + '_%s' % i)
        for i, widget in enumerate(self.widgets)]
    try:
        D = date(
            day=int(datelist[0]),
            month=int(datelist[1]),
            year=int(datelist[2]),
        )
```

a `MultiWidget` it's used with the `DateField` form field which takes a single value, so

> we have overridden this method to combine the data of all the
>   subwidgets into a `datetime.date`. The method extracts data from the
>   `POST` dictionary and constructs and validates the date. If it is valid,
>   we return the string, otherwise, we return an empty string which will
>   cause `form.is_valid` to return `False`.